# How to shift some lines of code backwards?

Tags: flutter, code-formatting

When I select some lines of code and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it shifts that selected code forward. So, what can I do when I need to shift a selected lines of code backward?

Please don't answer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: have you tried `shift+tab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press `shift + Tab` to backward the code.
you can also select the multiple lines and can press the `shift + Tab`

Answer (score 1):

Selecting your code and pressing shift + tab brings your code on step back.

Answer (score 1):

**helps you shifting forward and backward**

```
Ctrl + ] , Ctrl + [
```

**If you're using Vscode then press**

```
 Ctrl + Shift + i
```

**this automatically formats entire code**